# continuity of the function which is distance from the first conjugate point

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry, calculus-of-variations

Let $M$ be a smooth Riemannian manifold which is complete. For $p\in M$, let $U_pM$ denote the set of all unit vectors in $T_pM$. We define a function $s:U_pM\to [0,\infty]$ such that $s(v)$ denotes the distance function on $T_pM$ between the zero vector to its first [conjugate point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_points) along a geodesic $\gamma_v$.

I am having difficulty writing down this function explicitly and how I prove that this function is continuous.

Any help or reference will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $(M,g)$ is a complete Riemannian manifold.  Let $UM=\{(x,\xi)\in TM:|\xi|_g=1\}$, and let $\tau_c:UM\to[0,\infty]$ denote the conjugate distance function, i.e.,
$$\tau_c(x,\xi)=\inf\{t>0:d(\exp_x)_{t\xi}\text{ is degenerate}\}.$$

Suppose $\{(x_j,\xi_j)\}\subset UM$ is such that $(x_j,\xi_j)\to(x,\xi)\in UM$ and $T$ be any limit point of $\{\tau_c(x_j,\xi_j)\}$ in $[0,\infty]$.  For each $j$, let $\eta_j\in U_{x_j}M$ be such that
$$d(\exp_{x_j})_{\tau_c(x_j,\xi_j)\xi_j}(\eta_j)=0.$$
Since $x_j\to x$, $\{(x_j,\eta_j)\}$ is contained in a compact subset of $UM$, and so after possibly passing a subsequence, we may assume that $\eta_j\to\eta$ for some $\eta\in U_xM$.  Then by continuity of the exponential map, it follows that
$$d(\exp_x)_{T\xi}(\eta)=0,$$
and hence for the geodesic emanating from $(x,\xi)$, we conclude $\gamma_{x,\xi}(T)$ is conjugate to $x$, thus showing that $T=\tau_c(x,\xi)$ as desired.

Comment: Why does $\tau_c(x,v)=T$? I mean why this $T$ is the required limit, as it was just a choice.

Comment: @SachchidanandPrasad $T$ was chosen such that $\tau_c(x_j,\xi_j)\to T$ (or perhaps a subsequence) and we showed that $\gamma_{x,\xi}(T)$ is conjugate.  Hence $\tau_c(x,\xi)\leq T$.  If $T>\tau_c(x,\xi)$, then $\gamma_{x,\xi}(\tau_c(x,\xi))$ is an interior conjugate point, and so $\gamma_{x,\xi}$ is not minimizing between $x$ and $\gamma_{x,\xi}(T)$ which is a contraction since $\gamma_{x_j,\xi_j}\to\gamma_{x,\xi}$ and $\gamma_{x_j,\xi_j}$ are minimizing between $x_j$ and $\gamma_{x_j,\xi_j}(\tau_c(x_j,\xi_j))$.

Comment: Since $\gamma_{x_j,\xi_j}(\tau_c(x_j,\xi_j))\to \gamma_{x,\xi}(T)$ it must also be minimizing, but no geodesic can be minimizing after its first conjugate point.

Comment: My reference of choice for this material: Takashi Sakai's Riemannian geometry.

Comment: Thanks, it is clear now.

Comment: There is one problem that I am still having. You are proving the continuity of $\tau_c$ so one need to make sure that $\tau_c(x_j,\xi_j)\to T$. Could you please tell me why that convergence will hold because going through the subsequence will not solve the problem?